# Having the local directory in the PATH environment is not secure?

Tags: windows, shell, security, unix, path

In a lab, my professor writes:

> For security reasons, the local directory '.' is NOT part of the PATH environment variable [on Unix] (on Windows it is, though!).

The rest of the lab is unrelated to this issue and focuses on multithreaded programs, however this line bugs me - I have no idea how this is not secure or how it could be exploited on a Windows system.

Why might have the local directory in the PATH be insecure, and what kind of attack could this make possible?

Comment: The current directory can be removed from the implicit search path in Windows by setting the environment variable [`NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684269). For convenience, I sometimes add "." explicitly to the end of `PATH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To demonstrate the weakness,
consider the extreme case when `.` is the first entry in `PATH`.
If a malicious directory contains scripts named `ls` and `cd` that execute,
let's say, `rm -fr ~`, you'll be in for an unpleasant surprise.
These scripts will get executed instead of the standard commands,
since the files in the current directory will be found first.

Let's take the optimistic extreme case, when `.` is the last entry in `PATH`.
That's better, but still not so great.
The idea of `PATH` is to have entries that are absolute paths,
which are chosen deliberately as directories that contain programs that are safe to run.

Having `.` in `PATH` let's you run `prog` instead of `./prog`.
But this tiny convenience is not worth undermining your security.

Comment: This may be the case only if `.` is in front of standard paths

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès that's a very good point, thanks! (.... and had to rewrite my answer completely =)

Comment: When working interactively with scripts and executables in various directories, I find it both convenient and safe to append "." to `PATH` instead of typing "./" (or ".\" on Windows) repeatedly. What's not worth it is allowing Windows `CreateProcess` or CMD to implicitly search the current directory before system and `PATH` directories; I disable that legacy behavior.